# How can I render an image in several widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to render an image in several different image widgets, just like this photo:

[image: Cat image rendered in two widgets]

And add them to a column Widget. I have a restriction that each widget must not be taller than 120px. I have tried `SizedOverflowBox` with `ClipRect`, and `SizedBox` but didn't work.

This is how I'd doing using CSS (Obviously with some JS to generate dynamic DIVs and all the bells and whistles):

```
#top, #bottom {
  width: 240px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url("/img/cat.jpeg");
}

#top {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#bottom {
  background-position: 0 -120px;
}
```

That would generate something like this:

[image: Image split in two elements]

I haven't found any widget combination that allows me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Stack` widget (https://youtu.be/liEGSeD3Zt8). You can layer widgets on the z-axis using it. Then, add 2 children widgets to it where each is wrapped inside a `Positioned` widget (https://youtu.be/EgtPleVwxBQ). This will allow you to move the 2 children relative to each other in the `Stack`.